# Is investing in the shield stat points a waste if I later choose to dual wield / use 2-handed weapons?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I am new to the game and trying to decide where to put my points.  The [manual](http://epicgames.com/infinityblade/manual/index.html) seams to be a bit vague when it come to stat descriptions, however it does say:

> **Shield** - Additional blocking points.

So I assume this is useless if you are dual-wielding?

Also, is it possible to re-distribute the stat points at a later date?

Comment: Haven't played 2, but I know the first version has a button on the stats screen to purchase a respec.

Comment: I'd say that using a shield will still raise your blocking skill.  When you move to two-handed later, you will still benefit from the blocking tree so long as the blocking perk is not shield-specific.

Answer (score 1):

No, because 2 handed weapons, if you look, you can only use block, like shield, but it would be for duel weapons.

Answer (score 0):

While you still have a shield equipped when dual wielding or using a two handed weapon, you can't use it in either of these cases. Therefore if you never plan to use a one handed sword and shield, it would be a waste to increase your Shield stat.

I'm not aware of any way to respec your character, unfortunately.